# Grouping data within a CSV file

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to approach/understand how to group data with my current code.

The end goal is to create a density map with the decades along the x axis, then the number of occurrences along the y axis. After data cleansing the data set, it looks like so:

```
name,sex,first_appearence,franchise
Wonder Woman (Diana Prince),Female,1941,DC
Dinah Laurel Lance,Female,1969,DC
GenderTest,Female,1956,DC
Barbara Gordon,Female,1967,DC
Lois Lane,Female,1938,DC
```

I want to be able to add another column to the csv file where it assigns that row to a decade. So for example, the first row will be in group 1940, the second in group 1960, etc.

This is my current code of cleansing the data that I would like to update so it can group the data into decades:

```
var data = CSV.map(function(d) {
    return {
        name: d.name.replace(" (New Earth)", "").replace(" (Earth-One)", "").replace(" (Earth-Two)", "").replace(" (Earth-3)", ""),
        sex: d.SEX.replace(" Characters", ""),
        first_appearence: d.YEAR,
        franchise: "DC"
    }
});
females = data.filter(function (d) {
    return d.sex === "Female" && d.first_appearence !== "";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you could just add the column in your CSV.map function like so:

```
var data = CSV.map(function(d) {
return {
    name: d.name.replace(" (New Earth)", "").replace(" (Earth-One)", "").replace(" (Earth-Two)", "").replace(" (Earth-3)", ""),
    sex: d.SEX.replace(" Characters", ""),
    first_appearence: d.YEAR,
    franchise: "DC",
    decade: d.YEAR - (d.YEAR % 10)
}
});
```

This will set decade to the YEAR and subtract the single digit year (using [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)). I assume you are saving the result of the CSV.map back as a CSV file, otherwise you will need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`d3.nest()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nests) to group your data by decade. To transform your `first_appearance` into decade, you can simply divide it by 10, round it down to the nearest integer, and multiply it by 10 again, so you get a data transformation that is like this:

```
      /10          round down        *10
1965 —————→ 196.5 ————————————→ 196 —————→ 1960
```

So, the `.key` that you are using with `d3.nest()` will be the transformed decade, calculated based on the value of `first_appearance`:

```
var dataByDecade = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return Math.floor(d.first_appearance / 10) * 10; })
  .entries(data);
```

If your year is not transformed into numbers, remember to use the `+` operator to convert the string to a number, e.g. `first_appearence: +d.YEAR` when you're parsing the CSV. Of course, you can also do it at the step when you are performing the grouping, i.e.

```
var dataByDecade = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return Math.floor(+d.first_appearance / 10) * 10; })
  .entries(data);
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var data = [{
 name: 'Dinah Laurel Lance',
 sex: 'Female',
 first_appearance: 1969,
 franchise: 'DC'
},
{
 name: 'GenderTest',
 sex: 'Female',
 first_appearance: 1956,
 franchise: 'DC'
},
{
 name: 'Barbara Gordon',
 sex: 'Female',
 first_appearance: 1967,
 franchise: 'DC'
},
{
 name: 'Lois Lane',
 sex: 'Female',
 first_appearance: 1938,
 franchise: 'DC'
}];

var dataByDecade = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return Math.floor(d.first_appearance / 10) * 10; })
  .entries(data);
  
console.log(dataByDecade);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

Update: looks like you don't want to group your data, but instead append a column containing decade data. This can be done by doing this:

```
var data = CSV.map(function(d) {
    return {
        name: d.name.replace(" (New Earth)", "").replace(" (Earth-One)", "").replace(" (Earth-Two)", "").replace(" (Earth-3)", ""),
        sex: d.SEX.replace(" Characters", ""),
        first_appearence: d.YEAR,
        decade: Math.floor(+d.YEAR / 10) * 10;
        franchise: "DC"
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is good, but not what I wanted. I wanted  another column appended to the CSV called group, and if the year of that  row is 1955, it would be in group 1950. Thanks

Comment: @dumbquestionsbydumbpeople Then you can just do this: `decade: Math.floor(+d.YEAR / 10) * 10;`. See updated answer.